# Why will my discord bot not send a message in a channel discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

My python discord bot keeps getting errors when I tell it to send a message in a channel

```
@client.command()
async def log(ctx, msg):
channel = client.get_channel(852610465871036416)
await channel.message.send(msg)
```

PS: its fixed now

Comment: Which errors are you talking about? Simply use `channel.send(msg)`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
@client.command()
async def log(ctx, msg):
  await ctx.send(msg)
```

I'm Pretty Sure You Needed to Use ctx.send

Comment: also if you have any problems just leave a comment <3

Answer (score 0):

Tortle.py is completely right, however, you can do many forms of the `ctx.___("stuff")` . The first and simplest example would be `ctx.send("stuff")` , this will send the "stuff" in the channel where the user called the function (the thing the bot is doing.)

You could also do `ctx.author.send` this will DM (direct message) the author that called the function.

You could also do `ctx.reply` this will reply to the message that the user sends.

I hope you found this useful and feel free to like on this message for any extra support!

Answer (score 0):

in last line

```py
await channel.message.send(msg)
```

?
try it

```py
await channel.send(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def log(ctx, message):
   await ctx.get_channel(852610465871036416).send(“your message”)
```

This would work